# undefined method `get_category' for TestObserver:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In TestObserver class, I have self.delivered_email(message) method, the message is the action mailer instance, I'm calling get_category method in self.delivered_email method. But I received error message "undefined method `get_category' for TestObserver:Class". What is the problem and how could I solve it? I'm using observer pattern here in rails.

```
class TestObserver
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    begin
      category = get_category(message)
      # do something here
    rescue => ex
      # do something here
    end
  end

  private
  def get_category(message)
    # do something here 
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(TestObserver)
```

Comment: You are calling `get_category` from a class perspective, so you need to have that method defined as a class method. Just do `def self.get_category(message); end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, you are trying to access a instance method from a class method

your `self.delivered_email` is a class level method, if it calls other methods those should be class methods too. In this case `get_category(message)` is a instance method.

To fix the error you could make the `get_category(message)` as a class method. (if it fits your context)

```
class TestObserver
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    begin
      category = get_category(message)
      # do something here
    rescue => ex
      # do something here
    end
  end


  def self.get_category(message)
    # do something here 
  end
end
```

Comment: i see. why class method can only call class method?